# How to call a joomla module in virtuemart shop.browse page

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

How can a joomla module be called inside the virtuemart shop.browse page. I tried the following code inside the browse_layouttable.tpl.php but it is not working for me. I am using joomla1.5.23 and the virtuemart version is 1.1.8. Any suggestion?

```
<?php

           $modules =&  JModuleHelper::getModules('logo');
           foreach ($modules as $module)
           {
              echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($module)
           }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
     $document = &JFactory::getDocument();
     $renderer = $document->loadRenderer('module');

     $Module = &JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_fmDataGrid');

     $Params = "param1=bruno\n\rparam2=chris"; //if you want to pass params
     $Module->params = $Params;
     echo $renderer->render($Module);
```

Comment: I have tried with the following code but not showing the logo
$document = &JFactory::getDocument();
     $renderer = $document->loadRenderer('module');

     $Module = &JModuleHelper::getModule('logo');

     //$Params = "param1=bruno\n\rparam2=chris"; //if you want to pass params
     //$Module->params = $Params;
     echo $renderer->render($Module);

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I able to call a custom module with just to change few part of your code like
$Module = &JModuleHelper::getModule('custom','logo');

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use "Modules Anywhere" from NoNumber:
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/embed-a-include/6402

After you install this plugin you can add module positions directly in your browse page PHP using this example:
{modulepos mynewposition}

This is a must have plugin for all Joomla users, because you can use it throughout your site.